# How can i solve Access denied in PuTTY?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, putty

I am trying to use PuTTY. However when I tried to log in I get an Access denied error. I don't think the password is wrong because I use the same password and IP address with ssh when I connect to the Ubuntu server. In  /etc/ssh/sshd_config I changed PasswordAuthentication yes to fix the problem, but I got this error.

sshd_config:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWRsk.png)

The error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9OkU.jpg)

Any way to fix it?

EDIT:

After log all session:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58vZ0.png)

Comment: Is there an actual account called 'ubuntu' on the other side?

Comment: When I tried to connect i use: ssh ubuntu@XXX.xx.xx.xx That's why i am using here too.

Comment: So why did you use `ubuntu@`?

Comment: I can connect with this in ubuntu, what else i can use in PuTTY?

Comment: Set Putty to log all session output, try again to log in, and paste the contents of the log file into your question.

Comment: After all session output and trying again to log in > Error writing session log (raw mode) to file: putty.log
and i get the access denied error again.

Comment: You need to redirect the logging to a file in a directory that you have write access to. In Windows that would be something starting with `C:\Users\...`.

Comment: @Jos As you said that I redirect it (to my Desktop). However, i got the same error message.